# How do I make custom URL execute client side JavaScript? (SPA)

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I'm building an e-commerce and for some reason I wanted it to be SPA. Now that I'm almost done, there's no going back.

First I built a history using, well, history.pushState and popstate event. And navigating back and forth works fine, and blazing fast too.

The thing is, if the user navigates to a CPU section, pushState makes the link as following: localhost:2000/pages/cpu , and every page has a "link" of it's own. But if the user navigates to localhost:2000/pages/cpu express returns cannot get error. Which is obvious.

I'm really stuck and  only thing I could come up with the following:

```
const express = require('express');
const fs = require('fs');
const socket = require('socket.io');

const app = express();
const server = app.listen(2000);
const io = socket(server);

const paths = [
  {
    path: '/pages/games',
    msg: 'gamesRes',
  }, {
    path: '/pages/cpu',
    msg: 'cpuRes',
  }, {
    path: '/pages/play_station',
    msg: 'playStationRes',
  }
];

app.use('/client', express.static(__dirname + '/client'));

app.set('socketio', io);

app.get('/', (req, res) => res.sendFile(__dirname + '/client/index.html'));

paths.forEach(function(prop) {
  app.get(prop.path, function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/client/index.html');

    const io = req.app.get('socketio');
    const socketId = [];

    io.on('connection', function(socket) {
      socketId.push(socket.id);

      if(socketId[0] === socket.id) {
        io.removeAllListeners('connection');
      }
      // prop file has been moved to the client, so this does nothing ATM
      socket.emit(prop.msg, prop.file);
    });
  });
});

io.on('connection', function(socket) {
  // login, register, stuff.....
});
```

So next the client listens to the correct socket matching correct URL and renders the page. However, when he lands, socket connection gets closed, and login / register and other stuff is unusable. Is this approach good? Is it OK if I put my login, register and other socket events in the IO connection event inside app.get?
Is there some framework for this, since I don't think express is made for this king of job..

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ok I've been playing around with this for couple of weeks and I managed to get it to work.

First things first, create an array with all the URLs on the server:

```
const paths = [
  {
    path: '/pages/games',
    page: 'games',
  }, {
    path: '/pages/cpu',
    page: 'cpu',
  }, {
    path: '/pages/playStation',
    page: 'playStation',
  }
];
```

Next some express functions:

```
app.use('/client', express.static(__dirname + '/client'));
app.set('socketio', io); // so we can use it in app.get I guess
app.get('/', (req, res) => res.sendFile(__dirname + '/client/index.html'));
```

Problem is partly solved so far. If the user navigates to localhost:2000 he gets redirected to homepage. Now we need to attach other links:

```
paths.forEach(function(prop) {
  app.get(prop.path, function(req, res) {
    res.redirect('/');
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/client/index.html');

    const io = req.app.get('socketio');
    const socketId = [];

    io.on('connection', function(socket) {
      socketId.push(socket.id);

      if(socketId[0] === socket.id) {
        io.removeAllListeners('connection');
      }

      socket.emit('renderPage', {page: prop.page});

      // other listeners, login, register, etc...
    });
  });
});
```

So first off there was a bug that rendered same items over and over and stacked them if you kept re-freshing the page, but the `if(socketId[0] === socket.id)` check fixes that.
Now only thing we need to do on the client is:

```
socket.on('renderPage', function(data) {
  history.pushState({id: data.page}, '', `/pages/${data.page}`);
  pages[data.page]();
});
```

And client does the rest. I don't believe this is the best method, but it does work, and since I'm running short on time it'll have to do for now.

Any recommendation on improving this is very appreciated! I'm just a beginner in node and I actually don't understand why this works. It's all thanks to good old trial and error.

---

TFW you realize you could just do window.location on the client side and make routing from there. I don't even need express anymore. Nice XD I can't believe I always tend to make something extremely hard / impossible when there is the simplest solution in the whole universe...

Comment: You shouldn't use window.location with history api. They don't play very well together